# Create a struct that is generic over another generic struct

Tags: generics, struct, rust, dereference

I am trying to create a struct in Rust that is itself generic with respect to other generic structs. That's pretty confusing so hopefully this example will makes things clearer:

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo<T: Deref> {
    val: T<i32>,
    other: i32,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new(&self, val: T<i32>, other: i32) -> Self {
        Foo {val: val, other: other}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new(Rc::new(0), 0);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6657bbdae3d2b59461bdba5045d3d8b7&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I would like to be able to create a `Foo` object by calling `new` with either `Rc<i32>` objects or `Arc<i32>` objects depending on whether I need thread safety or not. I get the following error when I try this though: `error[E0109]: type parameters are not allowed on this type`, as the compiler complains about the `i32` in `val: T<i32>,`. Is this possible in Rust? If so, can I safely call methods on `i32` assuming it will auto dereference it?

Comment: Unlike some other languages, unfortunately Rust doesn't (yet) have higher kinded types, so type parameters have to be concrete types.  However in this case I agree with @Shepmaster that you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax doesn't make sense, but this version compiles:

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Foo<T> {
    val: T,
    other: i32,
}

impl<T> Foo<T>
    where T: Deref<Target = i32>
{
    pub fn new(val: T, other: i32) -> Self {
        Foo {
            val: val,
            other: other,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new(Rc::new(0), 0);
    let foo = Foo::new(Arc::new(0), 0);
}
```

Note how the trait bounds read: `T: Deref<Target = i32>` "Any `T` that implements `Deref` with a `Target` of an `i32`".

You can then implement methods that dereference `val`:

```
fn sum(&self) -> i32 {
    *self.val + self.other
}
```

---

In general, the concept of something like

```
struct Foo<T> {
    val: T<i32>,
}
```

Wouldn't prove useful. Just because something is parameterized over a `i32` doesn't mean you can *do* anything with that `i32`. Likewise, a type could be parameterized with something besides an `i32` (or not at all) and still give you access to an `i32`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! Going to try this out now. I would think this would be a more common technique as a way to quickly get a generic struct that can be thread safe or not depending on your needs, do you see this a lot?